# Windows HTML/CSS editor that has live preview?

Tags: windows, web-development, css, html-editor, live-preview

What is the best text editor for HTML/CSS that has **live preview**?

I use Sublime Text 3, but v3 has no live preview plug-in yet.

Comment: Actually, it does have an extension that provides live reload

Answer (score 5):

[Brackets](https://brackets.io) is a free, open source editor based on web technologies with a primary focus on web development. It is cross-platform and is backed by Adobe.

Using Live Preview, Brackets pushes code edits instantly to the browser to present an updated page without having to reload. However, Live Preview currently works **only on Google Chrome** (not even **Chromium!**). You cannot open Developer tools while using Live Preview.

It can push changes to CSS and HTML on typing, but Javascript changes are pushed on save. It also highlights the element selected by the cursor.

How to start Live Preview:

[image: How to open live preview in Brackets]

Comment: Might want to add some more details to your answer. At least explain how the live preview works, some of its limitations, as well as exactly what Brackets is. Do see [What is expected of an answer on this site](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/387/474).

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**, it could exists something better than a lightweight code editor from the team that developed the most powerfull and complete IDE environment for programmers (undeniably, unless you have not yet tested. ) ?

Please reffer to the indications in this StackOverflow post to see how to see the preview in the webbrowser:

- ***[How to view my HTML code in browser with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code)***

---

Just some images of the application:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor has an [atom live preview](https://atom.io/packages/atom-html-preview) plugin. From the documentation it looks like it does what you want.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Light Table](http://lighttable.com/) is an editor that evaluates blocks of code in many languages. The [docs show how to evaluate Javascript, HTML, and CSS](http://docs.lighttable.com/#with-javascript-html-css)

It looks like it's also possible to [connect to a browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zg6Nja8C9rU)